# HTTP POST requests fail after a certain number of requests - restarting Application Pool fixes it for a while

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, post, iis-7

I have an ASHX handler making POST requests to a separate website of mine. Everything works fine for the first ~200 requests. After that, all requests to that URL get the error "(500) Internal Server Error".

If I restart the Application Pool of the receiving website, it works for another 200 or so requests.

I turned off Rapid-Fail Protection and the limit on CPU actions in the Application Pool.

Any ideas on what could be causing this or how I can debug further? I didn't see any mention of the error in the IIS logs.

Comment: I wrapped the method that makes the request in a try..catch and grabbed the WebException...no useful information is recorded there at all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a sign of an unhandled exception in `ProcessRequest`. To be sure, try to wrap the method body in `try..catch` and log the exception somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what the issue was, but I found a fix.

On the end that is receiving the POST requests, instead of just firing the method I used ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() to queue it up. No more problems.